# ForeignKey relation a better understanding

Tags: django

If there is someone here from the Django world that can teach the best practices regarding field lookups , and how they work . I tried they're documentation but i found it very confusing specially the relation between models and views regarding databases .

For example let's say we have the following structure :
How should the view look and what is the best way to approach this kind of situations.

MODELS :

```
class Article(models.Model):

    Author  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Title   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Content = models.TextField()



class comments(models.Model):

    TheArticle = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    c_Author   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    c_Title    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    c_Content  = models.TextField()
```

View :

```
def page(request , URL_Title ): #comes trough the url setup 
   article = Article.objects.get( Title=URL_Title )
   comments = # What is the Django way in getting the comments for the specified article ?
   return render_to_response('base.html' , {'article':article , 'comments':comments } )
```

The Themplate :

```
{% if article %}
 .....Print all the article related fields .....
   {% if comments %}
      {% for comment in comments %}
         .....Print Comment .....
      {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

And if you have the time a example on a ManyToMany relation will also help .
Any help is highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [Following relationships "backward"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) it is possible to do so through `Manager` that will be automatically available on `Article` model instances. For manipulating related field see [ForeingKey.related_name attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

```
article = Article.objects.get( Title=URL_Title )
comments = article.comments_set.all()
```

Comment: Thx mate that was kind of you  , it really helped me .